# jQuery function never reaches else

Tags: jquery

I've been attempting to check and see if a particular text file exists when a button is pressed, and display an alert regarding whether it does or not. The best way I've come up with to address this is to check and see if the file contains any text (as I hold the text in the event it is there for display later on anyway).

The issue I've been running into is that while it works perfectly if there is a guide, but it never alerts the user if the guide doesn't exist.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#check_for_build').click(function(){

        var results = 'https://mywebpage.com/build-867-5309.txt';

        jQuery.get(results, function(data){
            if($(data).val().length == 0){
                alert('No build is currently available.');
            }
            else{
                alert('There is a build for this.');
            }

        });
    });
});
```

I'm a little dumbfounded, since it's a pretty simple if/else statement! Thank you!

Comment: Did you debug at all and check what the values are of `data` and `$(data)` in the case that is bothering you?

Comment: and presumably it is text, so $(data).val() - that would mean data have to be like  <input value="55" />

Comment: At one point I had the alert returning the length of the text document so that I could work with that, which was successful when there was a build to work with (as it would count the characters) but I still ran into the same issue of it never returning the length for no text document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the guide does not exist, you get http 404 which isn't a 'success' code, so success handler isn't called. Try this variant:

```
jQuery.get(results, function (data) {
   alert('There is a build for this.');
}).fail(function (err) {
   alert('No build is currently available.');
});
```